# E_ERROR: Class 'Mage' not found in magento

Tags: php, magento, session

I came across the following error happening only for a few of our users:

> E_ERROR: Class 'Mage' not found

It came from the following two core files

```
/path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Session.php (108)
/path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Session.php (185)
in Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Session::close called at ? (?)
```

it seems to be coming from core Magento file lines:

```
 if (is_null($this->_lifeTime)) {
            $configNode = Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin() ?
                    'admin/security/session_cookie_lifetime' : 'web/cookie/cookie_lifetime'; 


 public function close()
    {
        $this->gc($this->getLifeTime());

        return true;
    }
```

Is there a solution so that the problem never happens again? Has anyone came across this before? Any ideas.... speculations? .. :(

Comment: Check the var folder for permissions so he can save the session, also try checking if you have any limits on $_SESSION.

Comment: Other users can safely go through the site without any issues. So permissions should not be an issue? I am new to magento... How do I check limits on $_SESSION?

Comment: Please remove the session and cache folder from the var folder... if then its given this error then please give full comment line...